# Local footnotes with letters in longtable

Tags: footnotes, longtable

I have a document which has four numbered footnotes ("1" to "4") in the pages preceding a `longtable`. The table is split over two pages. A footnote inserted in the table with `\footnote{}` is numbered in sequence after the previous footnote and appears as "5" in the table.

To avoid confusion, I need footnotes in the table to appear as "a", "b", "c", etc. Changing the footnote labeling in the document to **letters** results in the table footnotes appearing as "e", "f", "g", etc.

Using `\footnotemark[1]{Footnote text}` resulted in a lettered footnote "a" appearing below the table, but there was no corresponding superscript mark next to the appropriate text in the table.

Is it possible to have local, lettered footnotes in a `longtable` in a document which has other, numbered footnotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be confusing your readers, probably. Anyhow, here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcounter{ltfootnote}
\renewcommand{\theltfootnote}{\alph{ltfootnote}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{ltfootnotes}
 {\let\c@footnote\c@ltfootnote
  \let\thefootnote\theltfootnote
  \setcounter{ltfootnote}{0}}
 {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A footnote\footnote{A}

B footnote\footnote{B}

C footnote\footnote{C}

D footnote\footnote{D}

\begin{ltfootnotes}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
a footnote\footnote{a} & b footnote\footnote{b} \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
x & y \\
\end{longtable}
\end{ltfootnotes}

E footnote\footnote{E}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The "E footnote" in the next page will be number 5.

Comment: Please explain why you think this will confuse the reader? My thinking is that footnotes in a table should be local. Reading a table where the first footnote is "e" would make it seem that the table should also contain footnotes "a" to "d". My intention is to separate footnotes in the textual part of the document, with those of a stand-alone entity like a table.